# Кастомный элемент в Android

Tags: android, view

Как сделать такой элемент? Создал класс наследуемый от `View`. Как его привязать его к файлу разметки и добавлять динамически. Яркий пример стена вконтакте, а именно посты. Для это нужно использовать `fragment`?

Answer (score 2):

После создания кастомного компонента, в разметке вам нужно указывать полный путь до класса этого компонента. Разместить вы его можете в любом контролле - и активити и фрагменте.

Например, вы создали кастомный `View` имя класса которого `MyView` со следующим package :

```
package com.example.mycustomview

public  class MyView extends View{

  ...
}
```

В любой разметке вы можете его разместить следующим образом:

```
<com.example.mycustomview.MyView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</com.example.mycustomview.MyView>
```

Для того, чтобы добавить динамически, нужно просто создать экземпляр этого класса и присоединить его к той `View`, к которой вы хотите его добавить, точно так же, как и с дефолтными виджетами системы.

В активити\фрагменте должна присутствовать разметка (здесь - main.xml) в которой содержится контейнер для размещения внутри себя вашего динамического `View` (здесь корневой `LinearLayout` с id - @+id/mainlayout):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

    MyView myView = new MyView(MainActivity.this);
    LayoutParams myViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    myView.setLayoutParams(myViewLayoutParams);
    mainLayout.addView(myView);
}
```

Comment: Который раз ловлю себя на мысли, что перед тем как задать вопрос, нужно в поисковике написать по-английски. Нашел статью, переведу и добавлю позже. Там описывается как сделать элемент, класс которого наследуется от `Layout`. В моём случае я использовал `RelativeLayout`.